# how to use OnEdit binding provider datagridview in dapper callback save to database ms access

Tags: dictionary, class, datagridview, callback, binding

how to use OnEdit binding provider datagridview in dapper callback save to database ms access.

I use nuget Kimtoo.BindingProvider and here is the info link https://kimtoo.gitbook.io/dgv-framework/binding-events/on-edit

how if I implement my code if I edit it in datagridview and then callback directly save it to database.

Thanks

```
  Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
'below is the code that must be modified to callback save to database
   grid.OnEdit(Of User)(Function(r, c) True)
            LoadData()
        End Sub
 Private Sub LoadData()
            Using connection As IDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
                Dim getUsersQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Users"
                Dim users As List(Of User) = connection.Query(Of User)(getUsersQuery).ToList()
                grid.Bind(users)
                grid.SearchRows(bunifuTextBox1.Text)
            End Using
        End Sub
Namespace DGVBindingImages.Data.Models
    <[Alias]("users")>
    Public Class User
        <AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey>
        Public Property Id() As Integer
        Public Property Name() As String = ""
        Public Property Phone() As String = ""
        Public Property Email() As String = ""
        Public Property Address() As String = ""
        Public Property Progress() As Integer
        Public Property Photo As Byte() = New Byte(-1) {}
    End Class
End Namespace
```

```
'procedure code in kimtoobindingprovider

Private oneditcallBack As Dictionary(Of DataGridView, Object) = New Dictionary(Of DataGridView, Object)()

    <__DynamicallyInvokable()>
        Public Function ContainsKey(key As TKey) As Boolean Implements System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue).ContainsKey, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary(Of TKey, TValue).ContainsKey
            Return Me.FindEntry(key) >= 0
        End Function
<__DynamicallyInvokable()>
        Public Sub Add(key As TKey, value As TValue) Implements System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue).Add
            Me.Insert(key, value, True)
        End Sub
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute()>
Public Shared Sub OnEdit(Of T)(dataGridView As DataGridView, callBack As Func(Of T, DataGridViewCell, Boolean))
    If Not DGVBindingProvider.oneditcallBack.ContainsKey(dataGridView) Then
        DGVBindingProvider.oneditcallBack.Add(dataGridView, callBack)
    End If
    DGVBindingProvider.oneditcallBack(dataGridView) = callBack
End Sub
```